# why kafka producer is not able to generare data

Tags: php, apache-kafka, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to Kafka and using it with PHP. I have installed  [arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka) as kafka php client. Following code, I am using to produce content, but It is not able to generate anything. Also, I was hoping when content would be generated, then it will be visible via consumer code. Is there any other way to cross-check whether the producer has generated content successfully or not? Also, most importantly, why this code is not able to generate anything?

```
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', 'localhost:9092');
$producer = new RdKafka\Producer($conf);
$topic = $producer->newTopic("test");
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, "Message $i");
    $producer->poll(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to cross-check whether the producer has
> generated content successfully or not?

Use [debug config](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md):

```
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('debug', 'all');
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', 'localhost:9092');
// ...
```

Comment: enabling debug won't fix the data generation problem

Comment: Debugging will help to understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flush](https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/rdkafka.flush.html).

1. After each message:

```php
$producer = new RdKafka\Producer($conf);
$topic = $producer->newTopic('test');
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, "Message $i");
    $producer->flush();
}
```

2. Batch producer:

```php
$producer = new RdKafka\Producer($conf);
$topic = $producer->newTopic('test');
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, "Message $i");
}
$producer->flush();
```

Comment: Please edit your existing answer to improve it instead of posting a new one.